# How to add forgot password feature in kivy using with firebase

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am new to kivy and kivymd so i am trying a website to be best in kivy. I always complete all task of this website. Bit now i am getting problem the website give a task that make a project and write a code from where the user can change password of his profile if he forgot means in easy way that make project implement forgot password where the user can change password of his profile using firebase code in python kivy

I am try to make it but i have no any idea what i write in code. I have created forgot password screen. But now what i do i have no idea please help me to complete this task oh soory
You are thinking that i can get solution from website which i am using but for solution i have to buy premium pack of the website